# Xamarin Forms App crashing at startup on iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin and not sure what I am doing wrong. I have packaged an enterprise app and currently trying to deploy it as ipa package. The app crashes at startup with the following trace. Really not sure how to proceed and what is the core reason of the crash

*Edit*. Updated stack trace after disabling assembly linking:

```
Thread 0 name:  tid_403  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018f2f7014 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f3bf450 pthread_kill + 112
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018f26b400 abort + 140
3   CrewConnectPlus.iOS             0x0000000100065604 mono_handle_native_sigsegv (mini-exceptions.c:2462)
4   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x000000018f3b9348 _sigtramp + 52
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f3bf450 pthread_kill + 112
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018f26b400 abort + 140
7   CrewConnectPlus.iOS             0x00000001001682b0 print_all_exceptions(MonoObject*) (runtime.m:991)
8   CrewConnectPlus.iOS             0x00000001000a2398 mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook (exception.c:1108)
9   CrewConnectPlus.iOS             0x0000000100065298 mono_handle_exception_internal (mini-exceptions.c:1810)
10  CrewConnectPlus.iOS             0x0000000100064374 mono_handle_exception (mini-exceptions.c:2039)
11  CrewConnectPlus.iOS             0x000000010005cbbc mono_arm_throw_exception (exceptions-arm64.c:410)
12  CrewConnectPlus.iOS             0x000000010067c248 throw_exception + 168
13  CrewConnectPlus.iOS             0x0000000100405e08 System_AppDomain_Load_System_Reflection_AssemblyName_System_Security_Policy_Evidence + 1000
14  CrewConnectPlus.iOS             0x0000000100405960 System_AppDomain_Load_System_Reflection_AssemblyName + 32
15  CrewConnectPlus.iOS             0x0000000100457884 System_Reflection_Assembly_Load_System_Reflection_AssemblyName + 36
16  CrewConnectPlus.iOS             0x00000001024712f8 Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_XamlParser_GetElementType_Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_XmlType_System_Xml_IXmlLineInfo_System_Reflection_Assembly_Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_XamlParseException_ (/C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlParser.cs:287)
17  CrewConnectPlus.iOS             0x00000001024687a0 Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_CreateValuesVisitor_Visit_Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_ElementNode_Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_INode (/C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\CreateValuesVisitor.cs:69)
18  CrewConnectPlus.iOS             0x0000000102463bac Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_ElementNode_Accept_Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_IXamlNodeVisitor_Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_INode (/C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlNode.cs:178)
19  CrewConnectPlus.iOS             0x0000000102463b10 Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_ElementNode_Accept_Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_IXamlNodeVisitor_Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_INode (/C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlNode.cs:173)
20  CrewConnectPlus.iOS             0x00000001024642a8 Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_RootNode_Accept_Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_IXamlNodeVisitor_Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_INode (/C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlNode.cs:224)
21  CrewConnectPlus.iOS             0x0000000102462820 Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_XamlLoader_Visit_Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_RootNode_Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_HydratationContext (/C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:122)
22  CrewConnectPlus.iOS             0x0000000102462298 Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_XamlLoader_Load_object_string (/C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:80)
23  CrewConnectPlus.iOS             0x0000000102461fec Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_XamlLoader_Load_object_System_Type (/C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:57)
24  CrewConnectPlus.iOS             0x0000000102461f60 Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_Extensions_LoadFromXaml_TXaml_REF_TXaml_REF_System_Type (/C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\ViewExtensions.cs:37)
25  CrewConnectPlus.iOS             0x000000010016f4e0 CrewConnectPlus_Messages_InitializeComponent (/<unknown>:1)
26  CrewConnectPlus.iOS             0x000000010016f1e0 CrewConnectPlus_Messages__ctor (/<unknown>:1)
27  CrewConnectPlus.iOS             0x000000010016ee14 CrewConnectPlus_App_GoToMainPage (/<unknown>:1)
28  CrewConnectPlus.iOS             0x000000010016ed9c CrewConnectPlus_App_SetMainPage (/<unknown>:1)
29  CrewConnectPlus.iOS             0x000000010016ed58 CrewConnectPlus_App__ctor (/<unknown>:1)
30  CrewConnectPlus.iOS             0x000000010016cc10 CrewConnectPlus_iOS_AppDelegate_FinishedLaunching_UIKit_UIApplication_Foundation_NSDictionary (/<unknown>:1)
```

OK finally managed to get a hand on a physical device and went through the Apple hassle of creating a dev provisioning profile in order to debug the issue:

It seems that my main xaml document (Messages.xaml) cannot load a dependent one (APMHeader.xaml).

Messages.xaml is given by:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:apm="clr-namespace:CrewConnectPlus;assembly=CrewConnectPlus"
    x:Class="CrewConnectPlus.Messages" Title="{Binding Title}" x:Name="BrowseItemsPage">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Sign All" Clicked="AddItem_Clicked" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <apm:APMHeader/> 
            <ListView x:Name="ItemsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="true" RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Padding="10">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Text}" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" FontSize="16" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Description}" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}" FontSize="13" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

And APMHeader is given by:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="CrewConnectPlus.APMHeader">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#25447A" HorizontalOptions="Fill" HeightRequest="100">
            <Label Margin="10">
                <Label.TextColor>Yellow</Label.TextColor>
                <Label.Text>Anwar Ludin</Label.Text>
            </Label>
            <Label Margin="10">
                <Label.TextColor>White</Label.TextColor>
                <Label.Text>ALU</Label.Text>
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

And the error is:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 11:5. Type apm:APMHeader not found in xmlns clr-namespace:CrewConnectPlus;assembly=CrewConnectPlus
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.CreateValuesVisitor.Visit (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode node, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode)
```

This works perfectly well on an Android device and the iPhone simulator. Not sure what is different on a physical device. I also checked that the output assembly name is `CrewConnectPlus`

Comment: Check your build settings, disable assembly linking for both Debug and Release and retry - at least that's what I'd try first but your problem may be elsewhere

Comment: OK disabled assembly linking and getting more info in the trace (see edit)...but still no idea whats wrong! :(

Comment: It's trying to init your main XAML page, post the XAML + .cs

Comment: Yes thanks for the advice. I managed to pin down the problem from a XAML document not being loaded correctly. However this seems to work just fine on android.

Answer (score -1):

I'm (very) late to this party, but the way you set properties looks weird.

Try changing:

```
 <Label Margin="10">
                <Label.TextColor>Yellow</Label.TextColor>
                <Label.Text>Anwar Ludin</Label.Text>
            </Label>
```

to

```
 <Label Margin="10" TextColor="Yellow" Text="Anwar Ludin">
            </Label>
```

Plus its more concise, so there's that.