# xamarin ios app crashes on physical devices

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have application posted on testflight. It works on android and on ios simulator, but on all iphone's its crashing on application starts. I have crashlog

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 6 Abort trap: 6

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001e72a5578 __pthread_kill + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000208120118 pthread_kill + 268 (pthread.c:1670)
2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x00000001af868c04 __abort + 128 (abort.c:155)
3   libsystem_c.dylib              0x00000001af810184 abort + 192 (abort.c:126)
4   AppName                        0x00000001075855dc 0x104240000 + 53761500
5   AppName                        0x000000010744ce2c 0x104240000 + 52481580
6   AppName                        0x00000001073e1f24 0x104240000 + 52043556
7   AppName                        0x00000001073e08f8 0x104240000 + 52037880
8   AppName                        0x00000001073d65f0 0x104240000 + 51996144
9   AppName                        0x0000000104721eac 0x104240000 + 5119660
10  AppName                        0x0000000105b3f934 0x104240000 + 26212660
11  AppName                        0x0000000105b58a40 0x104240000 + 26315328
12  AppName                        0x0000000105b59404 0x104240000 + 26317828
13  AppName                        0x0000000105b56780 0x104240000 + 26306432
14  AppName                        0x0000000105b54ba8 0x104240000 + 26299304
15  AppName                        0x0000000105b54608 0x104240000 + 26297864
16  AppName                        0x0000000105b541b8 0x104240000 + 26296760
17  AppName                        0x0000000105b53730 0x104240000 + 26294064
18  AppName                        0x0000000104868c4c 0x104240000 + 6458444
19  AppName                        0x0000000105760d94 0x104240000 + 22154644
20  AppName                        0x000000010576000c 0x104240000 + 22151180
21  AppName                        0x000000010431f888 0x104240000 + 915592
22  AppName                        0x00000001046e0c30 0x104240000 + 4852784
23  AppName                        0x00000001073f3ce8 0x104240000 + 52116712
24  AppName                        0x00000001074ad934 0x104240000 + 52877620
25  AppName                        0x00000001074b1174 0x104240000 + 52892020
26  AppName                        0x00000001042d6ed8 0x104240000 + 618200
27  AppName                        0x00000001042d75e8 0x104240000 + 620008
28  UIKitCore                      0x00000001aa6a3054 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 300 (UIApplication.m:2537)
29  UIKitCore                      0x00000001aa6a278c -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesWithActions:forCanvas:payload:fromOriginatingProcess:] + 2848 (UIApplication.m:2968)
30  UIKitCore                      0x00000001aa6a1768 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 856 (UIApplication.m:4782)
31  UIKitCore                      0x00000001aa6a13b4 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 132 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:451)
32  UIKitCore                      0x00000001aa3e9664 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 112 (_UISceneLifecycleState.m:109)
33  UIKitCore                      0x00000001aa727850 __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 216 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:567)
34  UIKitCore                      0x00000001aa5d9c5c -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 220 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:516)
35  UIKitCore                      0x00000001aa5d9a84 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 620 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:566)
36  UIKitCore                      0x00000001aa5d9634 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 252 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:469)
37  UIKitCore                      0x00000001aa5d9500 __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block... + 148 (_UIWindow
38  UIKitCore                      0x00000001aacc6a68 +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:fromCurrentState:actions:completion:] + 736 (BSAnimationSettings+UIKit.m:54)
39  UIKitCore                      0x00000001aad65074 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContextAndCompletion + 224 (_UISceneSettingsDiffAction.m:27)
40  UIKitCore                      0x00000001aa486c70 -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 316 (_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction.m:58)
41  UIKitCore                      0x00000001aa8f81ac __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.223 + 556 (UIScene.m:2007)
42  UIKitCore                      0x00000001aa557c60 -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 216 (UIScene.m:1683)
43  UIKitCore                      0x00000001aa557ad0 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 244 (UIScene.m:1969)
44  UIKitCore                      0x00000001aa557028 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 520 (UIApplication.m:4231)
45  UIKitCore                      0x00000001aa556db4 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 288 (UIApplicationSceneClientAgent.m:47)
46  FrontBoardServices             0x00000001be3642e4 -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 344 (FBSScene.m:440)
47  FrontBoardServices             0x00000001be3a4068 __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.80 + 120 (FBSWorkspaceScenesClient.m:394)
48  FrontBoardServices             0x00000001be368120 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 168 (FBSWorkspace.m:359)
49  FrontBoardServices             0x00000001be3a3cc0 __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 360 (FBSWorkspaceScenesClient.m:393)
50  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001af7afeac _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)
51  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001af7b391c _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 264 (queue.c:496)
52  FrontBoardServices             0x00000001be37224c __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 52 (FBSSerialQueue.m:157)
53  FrontBoardServices             0x00000001be371de8 -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 220 (FBSSerialQueue.m:181)
54  FrontBoardServices             0x00000001be374694 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 28 (FBSSerialQueue.m:194)
55  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001a83b2128 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28 (CFRunLoop.c:1957)
56  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001a83be7b4 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176 (CFRunLoop.c:2001)
57  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001a8343648 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 340 (CFRunLoop.c:2046)
58  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001a83590d4 __CFRunLoopRun + 828 (CFRunLoop.c:2953)
59  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001a835e3ec CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612 (CFRunLoop.c:3418)
60  GraphicsServices               0x00000001e387435c GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2196)
61  UIKitCore                      0x00000001aa6eaf58 -[UIApplication _run] + 888 (UIApplication.m:3782)
62  UIKitCore                      0x00000001aa6eabbc UIApplicationMain + 340 (UIApplication.m:5372)
63  AppName                        0x000000010757aab4 0x104240000 + 53717684
64  AppName                        0x00000001054179b8 0x104240000 + 18708920
65  AppName                        0x00000001053631bc 0x104240000 + 17969596
66  AppName                        0x0000000105363360 0x104240000 + 17970016
67  AppName                        0x000000010431f7f4 0x104240000 + 915444
68  AppName                        0x00000001046e0c30 0x104240000 + 4852784
69  AppName                        0x00000001073f3ce8 0x104240000 + 52116712
70  AppName                        0x00000001074ad934 0x104240000 + 52877620
71  AppName                        0x00000001074b3c3c 0x104240000 + 52902972
72  AppName                        0x00000001073d1ff8 0x104240000 + 51978232
73  AppName                        0x000000010758e160 0x104240000 + 53797216
74  AppName                        0x000000010431d514 0x104240000 + 906516
75  dyld                           0x00000001c7890dec start + 2220 (dyldMain.cpp:1165)
```

And here is part of the symbolicated stack trace

```
xamarin_find_protocol_wrapper_type (runtime.m:1194)
mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook (exception.c:1299)
mono_handle_exception_internal (mini-exceptions.c:2783)
mono_handle_exception (mini-exceptions.c:3107)
mono_arm_throw_exception (exceptions-arm64.c:403)
mono_arm_throw_exception (exceptions-arm64.c:403)
Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_CreateValuesVisitor_Visit_Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_ElementNode_Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_INode  (/D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\CreateValuesVisitor.cs:123)
Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_ElementNode_Accept_Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_IXamlNodeVisitor_Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_INode  (/D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlNode.cs:160)
Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_RootNode_Accept_Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_IXamlNodeVisitor_Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_INode (/D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlNode.cs:210)
Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_XamlLoader_Visit_Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_RootNode_Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_HydrationContext_bool (/D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:234)
Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_XamlLoader_Load_object_string_System_Reflection_Assembly (/D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:78)
Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_Extensions_LoadFromXaml_TXaml_REF_TXaml_REF_string_System_Reflection_Assembly (/D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\ViewExtensions.cs:50)
Xamarin_Forms_Xaml_ResourcesLoader_CreateFromResource_T_REF_string_System_Reflection_Assembly_System_Xml_IXmlLineInfo (/D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\ResourcesLoader.cs:40)
Xamarin_Forms_ResourceDictionary_SetAndLoadSource_System_Uri_string_System_Reflection_Assembly_System_Xml_IXmlLineInfo (/D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\ResourceDictionary.cs:76)
App__ctor (App.xaml.cs:15)
iOS_AppDelegate_FinishedLaunching_UIKit_UIApplication_Foundation_NSDictionary (/<unknown>:1)
...
```

code from AppDelegate:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
    Xamarin.Forms.Svg.iOS.SvgImage.Init();
    SfListViewRenderer.Init();
    SfCalendarRenderer.Init();
    SfAvatarViewRenderer.Init();
    SfBadgeViewRenderer.Init();
    SfBorderRenderer.Init();
    SfTimePickerRenderer.Init();
    DependencyService.Register<IRecordAudio, RecordAudio>();
    DependencyService.Register<IAudioPlayer, AudioPlayer>();
    LoadApplication(new App());
    FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(options, true);

    return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```

code from App ctor:

```
public App()
{  
 Syncfusion.Licensing.SyncfusionLicenseProvider.RegisterLicense("key");
 InitializeComponent();
}
```

Xcode 14.3.1
VSMac 17.6.3

Maybe anybody knows how to fix it?

All .net components updated. Xcode and VSMac newest version. In ios project properties tried to select all linking variants. Target ios - 11.0

Comment: Where does it crash?  What is it doing when it crashes?  Do you have any exception handling or .NET error reporting tool installed?

Comment: @Jason it crashing on iphone 11 and iphone 13 pro. Crashing onStart app. i dont have any .NET error reporting tool installed

Comment: the following example failed due to not using an enumeration.  See last answer for the solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42938736/xamarin-forms-app-crashing-at-startup-on-ios

Comment: @jdweng sorry, i am little confused. In last answer shown example about using another type of setting properties. Are you sure that this is correct link?

Comment: Error is due to NSDictionary having a null key : Foundation_NSDictionary (/<unknown>:1)  See Foundation_NSDictionary (/<unknown>:1) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary  See if following helps.  Not sure why it only happens on some machines : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44214182/adding-key-values-to-nsdictionary-misses-keys

Comment: @jdweng Are you sure that this can help? I an not changing something in NSDictionary. My AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching code:

Comment: @avveshka Please don't post code in comments. You should add this to the question if it's relevant.